# Lenovo B490 Bios update failed?

Tags: boot, keyboard-shortcuts, motherboard, bios

I have updated my official bios from [Lenovo](http://support.lenovo.com/in/hi/downloads/ds032260)

When I try to update my BIOS the Bios got corrupted and system doesn't boot-up, After googling I found some procedure to recover it, But I am struck in that process.

1. Download Phoenix Wincrisis on another computer, then click on *WINCRIS.exe* and choose *CREATE MINIDOS CRISIS DISK* and press *Start* to make: USB floppy or USB flash memory.
2. Rename your BIOS file H9ET2WW.cap to bios.wph and copy it to the USB stick.
3. Plug the USB stick into the laptop and shutdown.
4. Hold down the keys <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and while holding press the power button.
5. Now you should hear the floppy drive working or USB blinking. Hold the keys for a while.
6. Leave the computer for few minutes. If it does not restart itself, turn the power off.

---

However, I can’t go after Step 4, since <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> hotkey doesn't work!

Correct me if I have missed any steps or I need any other hotkey combination. I have tried these combinations:

- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>