# Lenovo B490 BIOS Recovery

Tags: bios, flash, recovery

Has anyone successfully recovered/flashed B490 laptop without removing the flash from board?

I tried:

1. Download Phoenix Wincrisis on another computer, then click on `WINCRIS.exe` and choose `CREATE MINIDOS CRISIS DISK` and press `Start` to make: USB floppy or USB flash memory.
2. Rename your BIOS file `H9ET2WW.cap` to `bios.wph` and copy it to the USB stick.
3. Plug the USB stick into the laptop and shutdown.
4. Hold down the keys <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, and while holding press the <kbd>Power</kbd> button.
   Now you should hear the floppy drive working or USB blinking. Hold the keys for a while.
5. Leave the computer for few minutes. If it does not restart itself, turn the power off.

Comment: (1) What doesn't work with your recovery disk? (2) How come the BIOS is dead, and where does it fail during boot? (3) Can you boot into the BIOS?

Comment: See if you can start in BIOS.  If so, reset to Defaults and then see is it restarts. I needed to do that for aLenovo Desktop I no longer have

Comment: @harrymc I did Update the bios, after reboot nothing comes on. Power light glows only   fan rotate.
if try recovery by pheonix tric fn+r key usb flash few times and pc reboots then nothing.

Tried same like this one
https://superuser.com/questions/1011621/lenovo-b490-bios-update-failed

Comment: If you can't enter the BIOS and re-flashing fails, this might be a job for the repair guys.